# Axios Network Error, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED: React/Node app runs fine locally but getting error in Heroku production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios, connection-refused

I have a React/Node app that posts to MongoDB Atlas using Axios. Locally, the app makes calls successfully, but after deploying it on Heroku, I'm getting the following error message in the console:

POST http://localhost net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED; Uncaught (in promise) o {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK

React Frontend:

```
 const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newConnection = {
        firstName: input.firstName, 
        lastName: input.lastName,
        email: input.email,
        comments: input.comments,
        date: new Date()
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/create', newConnection)
    
    window.alert("Thank you! We will be in touch soon.")
}
```

Backend Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Connection = require("../models/connectionModel");
    
router.route("/create").post((req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const comments = req.body.comments;
    const date = req.body.date;
    const newConnection = new Connection({
        firstName, 
        lastName,
        email,
        comments,
        date
    });

    newConnection.save();
})

module.exports = router;
```

Backend Server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path'); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./frontend/build")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

app.use("/", require("./routes/connectionRoute"));

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('express server is running on port 3001')
})
```

After combing the web for solutions, I confirmed that the express server is running on port 3001 and that I have CORS enabled. It's possible that there's an issue with the url I'm using in the axios.post request, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `localhost`. once you deploy you need to call to API url.

create a way to get the `API_URL` from environment variable for react.

```
API_URL=https://your-heroku-url.com
```

```
axios.post(`${API_URL}/create`, newConnection)
```

Comment: Thanks, @chathula! Your solution, combined with updating the url for "proxy" in my react package.json to the API url, fixed my code! I appreciate your quick assistance.